# Where is the prayer that contains the words "תן בינה לרופא"?

Tags: tefilla, choleh-sick

I have been told that there is a prayer that a sick person can say requesting healing which contains the words, "תן בינה לרופא".

Can anyone identify this prayer?

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=2YQNAAAAYAAJ&pg=PP642&lpg=PP642 has _chon_ in place of _ten_.

Answer (score 1):

I think the phrase you are looking for is `חֹן בינה לרופא` - *grant wisdom to the Doctor*.

You can find a prayer containing these words - with vowels -  on [page 1058](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_34254_1079.pdf) of the Hertz Siddur - available [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/34254).

> אנא יי רופא כל בשר • רחם עלי וסעדני בחסדך
>    הגדול על ערש דוי : שלח לי תרופה ותעלה בתוך
>     שאר חולי בניך: רפא את מכאבי וחדש כנשר
>    נעורי: **חֹן בינה לרופא** ויגהה ממני מזורי • וארוכתי
>    מהרה תצמח:‏

Answer (score 1):

My wife pointed out to me that the [“Singer's Prayer Book” '06, 5767](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Hebrew-Daily-Prayer-Jonathan-Sacks/dp/0007200935) edition has a “Prayer for recovery from illness”. It is slightly different to the one of the Hertz Siddur and has indeed the version:

> "תן בינה לרופא"

and not "חֹן" .